# How can I test my app after it is uploaded to the Play Store?

Tags: android, testing, mobile, google-play, google-play-console

So I like always to test my app after it is uploaded to the Play Store to see what the users are downloading. But, I am afraid that downloading my own app could be a reason of ban or limitation of my app ( I guess that downloading your own app is like buying your own product as it will count as +1 download, so it is like cheating although the end goal is to test my app). So, what would be the correct way to test my app after it is uploaded to the Play Store? Thanks

Comment: You can just download it without worries, you won't be banned and it's not a cheat ;) You can also use any types of testing (alpha, closed, internal - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en) before the actual publishing to the end users of your app - it simplifies any smoke tests or billing tests or smth similar. Thereby you can install your app before anyone else and check what's needed and publish it afterwards.

Comment: But why? You can install app directly from an apk file. Feel free for install any own apps from Google Play.

Comment: @Style-7 so how can I feel free for installing my own apps ? Is there any reference that says that it is OK to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can install your own App, also your employees can install it for testing.

when you install your app that have IAP, you can buy it without paying any money. this is the proof that Google Allow it.

What counts as a violation:

1. Clicking on your own app's Ads (you, your employees, your family or your friends)
2. Creating a lot of accounts just for the reason of inflating the number of installs

Comment: What happens if I have many google accounts but I only install it in one account? I mean, were you wanted to say "installing your app with many different accounts" than "Creating a lot of accounts". Because I actually create many accounts but I only install the app in one account.